# Get fuzzy matches (discarding exact match) for each element in a list to itself using Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to get fuzzy matches for each element in a list to itself using Power Query discarding all exact matches

I can do this using VBA but it takes up to 15 minutes to run a large list and Power Query solution seems like a perfect method for this

But when I try this in Power query using merge queries all I get are exact matches

Thanks

List

[image]

Example

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing.  I get multiple matches in powerquery with this fuzzy matching code:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, #"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Changed Type", JoinKind.LeftOuter, [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true])
in  #"Merged Queries"
```

[image]